# Is the point of a shape with the greatest average ray length also the "centroid"?

Tags: integration, euclidean-geometry, average, centroid

By a shape I mean one with a enclosed area. One example can be with $x^2+y^2+\sin{4x}+\sin{4y}=4$. I am dealing with implicit relations on a 2-d plane.

By the "ray length" I mean the length of the line segment from any chosen point inside the enclosed area to a point on the boundary of the shape.

Just in case you do not know how to find the average ray length you can start by converting an implicit relation into polar form. Just substitute $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ in $f(x,y)=0$.

Then to choose a point inside an implicit relation just convert $f(x+u,y+v)=0$ (because we want our chosen point at the pole) and with substitution get $f(r\cos\theta+u,r\sin\theta+v)$. From here you solve for $r$ In terms of $\theta$ $u$ and $v$ as $r=g(\theta)$ then take the area as $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2{\pi}}g(\theta){d\theta}$ and find the $u$ and $v$ (u,v) with the greatest area. If this is not possible you could implicitly find the area under $f(r\cos\theta+u,r\sin\theta+v){d\theta}$ ,where $r>0$ and the area between $0<\theta<2\pi$. Then divide the area by $2\pi$ and once again find the $u$ and $v$ in point (u,v) with the greatest area.

(If you are not clear with how the area should be calculated treat the polar equation as cartesian implicit function. Replace $r=y$ and $\theta=x$ to get $f(y\cos{x}+u,y\sin{x}+v)$ and then proceed.

Here is an example with the circle https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/38a501f2-5b63-4b76-b720-6cadb9c3e142

The centroid can be found online in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid.

When it came to a circle and ellipse I found the point of "highest average ray length" and "center of mass" to be the same. However I am not sure how to figure this out with more complicated implicit relations like $x^2+y^2+\sin{4x}+\sin{4y}=4$. Are there any approaches to finding the difference using calculus or numerical integration?

Comment: For a circle of radius 1, I got that the average radius at the center is $\frac{2}{3}$, and that the radius from a point on the boundary is $\frac{32}{9\pi}\approx 1.13$. So I'm not sure how you got the conclusion about "highest average radius" for the circle.

Comment: Oh if you followed my procedure I cant understand but if not the average radius should be 1 in the center . At the boundary I got the average radius approximately .6366197. I'll clarify my procedure.

Comment: I was looking at the average radius to points in an *enclosed* region, and not to the points on the boundary. My mistake.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your calculations for the point on the boundary of a circle, i.e. the integral you were evaluating? Your definition of average radius is not at all syncing with my intuition of what it should be.

Comment: "Please login to https://cloud.sagemath.com with cookies enabled, then refresh this page."

Comment: I apologize hopefully this https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/38a501f2-5b63-4b76-b720-6cadb9c3e142 will help.

Comment: I have made my last edit. Hopefully someone will check the link.

Comment: Concerning the edit and the post at the Mathematica site.  As I mentioned before, the specification to integrate against $d\theta$ is not an averaging procedure.  The weights of different intervals of the curve vary as a function of the center point of the rays, because they subtend different angles with respect to different center points.  For your question to make sense, there needs to be one agreed upon measure on the curve, and the centroid and all the centerpoint averages are calculated with respect to that measure.

Comment: @zyx Instead of $d\theta$ what would be an appropriate variable of integration. Perhaps I should use the definition stated in Rahul's answer down below.

Comment: Consider the simpler problem of defining the average distance from a point $P=(a,b)$ to the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$.   I would imagine the natural choice is $\int_0^1 \sqrt{(a-x)^2 + b^2} dx$.  This equals the limit of the arithmetic mean of distances from $(a,b)$ to $n$ points subdividing the segment into equal parts, and is also equal to the expected value of the distance from $(a,b)$ to $(x,0)$ for a randomly chosen $x$ (with respect to uniform probability measure) in $[0,1]$.  Is this how you would define the average distance for this case?  It is different from $d\theta_P$.

Comment: @zyx Sorry for the delay. I am mainly focusing on $2$-d closed shapes instead of line segments. Also you cannot just use any parameter to find the average ray length from a point. The angle between the rays from point $(u,v)$ to the other parametric curve must be the same. In this Hopefully this could help https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m1ccc3t7er460j/PDFF2333.pdf?dl=0. So then could I use $dt$ instead?

Comment: @zyx What I'm trying to take the average distance it not that arc length must be equal from point $(u,v)$ it's the angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confused you with the definition of mean radius with the average ray length. When people think of average radius they think of "average squared minimized" or mean radius.

What I am focusing on was more of average ray length, where a ray is from a point inside an enclosed shape point on the boundary of the shape. Then as the angle of the ray (in radians) shifts from $0$ to $2\pi$ the ray length for each $\theta$ created a "ray function" or $r(\theta)$. I want find the average of that ray function from $0$ to $2\pi$.

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r(\theta)$$

I asked a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103134/help-with-finding-the-points-inside-a-closed-shape-with-the-highest-average-ra) where the user @Rahul understood what I meant and gave a better explanation.

"Suppose the curve is star-shaped with respect to your center point $\mathbf p=(u,v)$, so that any ray emanating from $\mathbf p$ meets the curve exactly once, at say point $\mathbf q$. Then $r = \|\mathbf q - \mathbf p\|$, $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf q-\mathbf p$ and the $x$-axis, and the average radius is"
$$\frac1{2\pi}\oint_{\mathbf q\in\mathcal C}\|\mathbf q-\mathbf p\|\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Using a software technique he was able to find the point with the highest average ray length for $x^2+y^2+\sin(4x)+\sin(4y)=4$. While the centroid was $(-.163523,-.070653)$ the point of highest average ray length is $(-.052594,-.052505)$.

Despite this counter-example I found for circles, ellipses, rectangles and many simpler enclosed shapes; the centroid is the point with the highest average ray length.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider a C-shaped area, where the center of mass is obviously outside of the shape, and cannot be within the shape. Perhaps you might want to consider convex shapes but even with those I do not believe center of mass is the point of the highest average radius. I think your idea could only (perhaps) work if you only consider the boundary of the shape and its mass (but the area within has no mass).

Comment: Do you know of other kinds of centers I can look into? I think there could be other centers related to that of the average radius.

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centroids and you might also want to look into the center of mass of curve segments.

Comment: I realized by center of mass I meant centroid. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is it okay if you modify your answer.

Comment: Here is the link https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/38a501f2-5b63-4b76-b720-6cadb9c3e142 to clarify your result.

Answer (score 1):

The centroid is the point from which the average **squared** radius is **minimized**, but there is no such extremum characterization involving the average radius itself.

The only nonconstant functions $f(r)$ of the "radius" for which the centroid is always a point at which the average value of $f(r)$ is extremal, are $f(r)= Ar^2 + B$ for constant $A$ and $B$.

---

Updated after the edit to the question.

The preceding statements are correct for a given integration measure on the figure.  The centroid and the average squared radius are computed with respect to that measure, whichever it may be.

If "figure" is meant as the interior of the curve then area measure is the standard choice and is what is always meant when speaking of centroids.   If the curve is imagined as a bent physical wire of uniform density, the center of gravity of the wire is not the centroid of the 2-dimensional region bounded by the curve.

Using $d\theta$ relative to the center point of the rays as integration measure on the curve is not an averaging procedure, because the measure of intervals on the curve depends on the center point.

Comment: Are you talking about the radius of gyration?

Comment: For point $P$, the average of $|PX|^2$, for $X$ in the figure.

Comment: So this is how to find the average radius from a centroid?

Comment: It is a quantity that is minimized when P is the centroid.  If you are asking how to compute the average for a given P that is a different question (answered in any multivariable calculus textbook).  I don't think there is any other function of distance (to P) that is minimized at the centroid except squared distance.

Comment: There exists such an extremism with the average please check https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/38a501f2-5b63-4b76-b720-6cadb9c3e142

Comment: I doubt it, for the reasons stated in the answer.   Also, your integral using $d\theta$ is not an averaging procedure, because the weighting of the points depends on P from which the radii are measured.  Average means weights independent of P.

Comment: So the unit circle having the highest average radius at the centroid is part of $f(r)=Ar^{2}+b$? Please check my link for calculations just in case. https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/38a501f2-5b63-4b76-b720-6cadb9c3e142

Comment: That is (postable as) a separate question about the circle and not general shapes.   Surely the statement is correct, the difficulty is in proving it for general points P inside the circle.  A reasonable guess is that average(P) increases as P moves closer to the circle.

Comment: thanks for your help I appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

So here's something interesting I found about your definition.

To recapitulate: You have a closed curve $\mathcal C$, and you choose an arbitrary point $\mathbf p$ in its interior. For any angle $\theta$ you shoot a ray from $\mathbf p$ at an angle $\theta$ to the $x$-axis, and define $r$ to be the distance from $\mathbf p$ to the point $\mathbf q$ where the ray hits $\mathcal C$. (Ignore for the moment that $r$ is only a function of $\theta$ if the region is star-shaped with respect to $\mathbf p$.) Your average ray length is
$$\bar r = \frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}r\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Now if you consider a differential element of length $\mathrm d\ell$ along the curve, a little geometry shows that
$$r\,\mathrm d\theta = \cos\phi\,\mathrm d\ell,$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between the vector $\mathbf r = \mathbf q - \mathbf p$ and the normal to the curve at $\mathbf q$. Furthermore,
$$\cos\phi = \hat{\mathbf r}\cdot\hat{\mathbf n},$$
where $\hat{\mathbf r} = \mathbf r/\|\mathbf r\|$ and $\hat{\mathbf n}$ is the unit normal at $\mathbf q$. So the integral is really
$$\bar r = \frac1{2\pi}\oint_{\mathcal C} \hat{\mathbf r}\cdot\hat{\mathbf n}\,\mathrm d\ell.$$
Conveniently, this integral is well-defined even if the region is not star-shaped, and turns out to be equivalent to taking $r$ to be the *total* length of the ray that lies inside the curve.

Now that last integral is nothing but the total flux of the vector field $\hat{\mathbf r}$ through the closed curve $\mathcal C$, so we can apply the divergence theorem to find that
$$\begin{align}
\bar r &= \iint_{\mathcal A}(\nabla\cdot\hat{\mathbf r})\,\mathrm dA \\
&= \iint_{\mathcal R}\frac1r\,\mathrm dA,
\end{align}$$
where $\mathcal R$ is the region enclosed by $\mathcal C$. In other words, if we define the convolution kernel
$$h(\mathbf x) = \frac1{\|\mathbf x\|},$$
then the average ray length $\bar r$ as a function of $\mathbf p$ is a convolution
$$\bar r(\mathbf p) = \iint_{\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^2} h(\mathbf x-\mathbf p) 1_{\mathcal R}(\mathbf x)\,\mathrm dA,$$
or simply
$$\bar r = h*1_{\mathcal R},$$
where $1_{\mathcal R}$ is the indicator function of the region $\mathcal R$.

Comment: The integration measure $d\theta$ used to define "average distance from $p$" is a function of $p$, unlike $d\ell$ which depends only on the curve.  This is visible in the formula comparing $d\theta$ to $d\ell$.  The dependence on the center point of the rays makes it hard to interpret which $p$ is extremal since average($p_1$) and average($p_2$) are summing the ray lengths from the center in different ways.  It also is not possible to say if the centroid is extremal because centroid is undefined without a fixed measure on the curve.  To define "extremizer of average $r$" we need a measure.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying there is a flaw in my derivation? Note that in the formula $r\,\mathrm d\theta = \cos\phi\,\mathrm d\ell$ it is $\phi$ on the right-hand side that depends on $\mathbf p$.

Comment: I assumed that the derivation is flawless.  I am saying that your formulas make explicit why the formalization of "average ray length from P" as an integral with respect to uniform angle measure around P is not correct. The angle $d\theta$ subtended at P by an infinitesimal segment of length $d\ell$ on the curve varies with P and that is what the $\cos \phi$ term is picking up.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are taking issue with the definition itself. But how can a definition be incorrect? To me it is perfectly fine: it is the average taken from $\mathbf p$'s point of view. One can imagine speaking of how "the average brightness of the night sky" varies from place to place, without imposing a measure on all the stars in the galaxy.

Comment: That's a nice way to look at it (though I will have to think a bit to resolve whether it negates what I wrote previously).  But how are we supposed to compare the brightness to that from "the centroid" without imposing a measure so as to be able to calculate the centroid of the stars / curve?

Comment: Yeah I don't think the centroid really has anything to do with the average radius. I would just compute the centroid of the enclosed region in the usual way. (If we can measure angles we are presumably in Euclidean space so we already have a uniform area measure at our disposal.)

Comment: I think the "brightness of sky" example actually reinforces the idea that a measure is missing in the problem.  Luminosity is a measure imposed by the universe on all the stars in the galaxy.  The brightness from P's point of view is the sum of inverse-square distances to the stars weighted by that measure.   Now think of a galaxy whose equal-luminosity stars are at the points of a regular N-gon.   Clearly we want the average inverse square distance of those stars to P to have equal weight 1/N on all stars but this fails with the $d\theta$ measure.

Comment: What exactly is the function you're integrating over $\mathrm d\theta$ in that last sentence?

Comment: I'm saying that sectors at P with equal angle measure do not contain equal numbers of points (stars).   This can also be said in a limiting version for increasing N where the regular polygon converges to a circle, and the luminosity measure becomes uniform angle measure on the circle, but this differs from the $d\theta$ measure based at P (other than the center of the circle).  The function integrated against the continuous measures would be inverse square distance from P to points on the circle.

Comment: That's not quite right. The "average brightness of the sky" only makes sense as a measure of intensity *per unit (solid) angle*, i.e. *radiance*, so the quantity under the integral should also be a radiance. But the inverse square distance already gives the total intensity of the point source, not a radiance. For a continuous light source, radiance is actually independent of distance (things don't look darker the further you are from then).

Comment: I don't think this changes the argument about measures.  As long as multiplying the emission rate of a source by $k$ multiplies the rate of arrival of radiation from that source at P by $k$, the emission rate functions as a measure (a linear functional) in the sum or integral calculating the illumination quantity at P.  It might change the function being integrated.  I would interpret average brightness more as arrival rate of photons or photon energy in a region surrounding P.  Whatever it is, it is additive with respect to sources and each source's contribution is linear in emission rate.

Comment: My point is that the function you integrate over the unit circle (which is radiance divided by squared distance) is not the same as the function you should integrate over $\mathrm d\theta$ (which is radiance).

Comment: Suppose I am in a room with three white walls and one red wall, but I am really close to the red wall, so it subtends nearly $180^\circ$ from my perspective. Then if I spin around $360^\circ$, the average colour I see should be the 50-50 average of white and red. You can get this either by integrating colour/$r^2$ over all the walls of the room, or by integrating colour over $\mathrm d\theta$, but obviously integrating colour/$/r^2$ over $\mathrm d\theta$ like you are implying gives a different (and wrong) answer.

Comment: OK.  But in terms of the original problem with average radii and centroids, I am arguing that there is no equivalent interpretation with $d\theta$ so that one needs to specify a measure on the "walls of the room" = the given curve.  The $1/r^2$ is a special situation where a local interpretation can be chosen at the source or at the destination, because it is derived from a process with a symmetry of source and target (take emission cone of particles from the source landing near P and reverse it so P is the vertex).

Comment: You'll have to walk me through that logic. What exactly is wrong with $\mathrm d\theta$ here?

Comment: The argument with vertex sets of regular n-gons converging in measure to a circle (by keeping the same total mass at the vertices as n increases).  $r d\theta_P$ is not the limit of the arithmetic mean of the n distances from P to the vertices due to the cosine term in your formula for the relation to $d\ell$.  No $f(r) d\theta_P$ equals $d\ell$ either, for any function of $r$ that is independent of $P$.

Comment: We don't *want* the mean of the distances to all vertices of the polygon. We want the mean of the distances over rays in different directions emanating from $\mathbf p$. *That's the point.*

Comment: If you accept a priori all functions of the pair (point, curve) as equally good there is nothing to discuss.   I think, and I happen to think the OP would have agreed had he known the argument before posting, that the limit of symmetric finite point sets such as equal division of the perimeter of the square or circle into $4n$ parts shows "we" do not want the angular average from P, and that it was only in the question because the OP arrived at that formalization first.  Another bit of evidence for that is that centroid is undefined without the thing "we don't want", a measure.

Comment: But the angular average from $\mathbf p$ is the entirety of the question; if you remove it there is nothing left. You are now speculating about the OP's intent after rejecting all of their express statements.

Comment: The OP did not make any express statements clarifying that they really truly want the angle measure thing as the formalization, and did make statements about centroids of curves that are not logically consistent with the P-based angle measure.  You are expressly assigning the spectre of "speculating about OP's intent", though.  It's pretty clear that a lot of MSE questions say they want one thing but the textual evidence is that they are looking for something else.  Maybe OP will clarify at some point what he thinks the average distance from P to a line segment should be, for example.

Comment: A very specific example is P at distance $d$ to the midpoint of a unit line segment, on the perpendicular bisector of the segment.  By taking $d$ small enough, the angle-measure average length can be made arbitrarily close to $0$.  This conflicts with the idea that most of the points in the line segment are at a lower-bounded distance from P.

Comment: The fact that the harmonic mean of $\{0.1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ is $0.49$ also conflicts with the idea that most of the numbers in the set are no less than $1$. Anyway, I think I'm done with this conversation. Have a nice day/night.

Comment: Wait, I think I see the problem. You keep talking about measures over the curve. Why do we need a measure over the curve? We just need a measure over the space of directions emanating from $\mathbf p$, which is essentially the uniform measure on $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: The OP actually did use a regular N-gon model, here for example https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/38a501f2-5b63-4b76-b720-6cadb9c3e142   (the Riemann sum).

Comment: How is that an $n$-gon? It's just a Riemann sum.

Comment: The OP wrote, for the curve being a circle, and at first for P=(0,0), to calculate the average distance as the limit of the arithmetic mean of the distance $f_0(\theta)$ at vertices of an inscribed regular $n$-gon.  Then to do the same thing relative to $f_P(\theta)$, the distance to P = $(u,v)$.  Depending on how the procedure is ported to the new center point, one gets either the angle measure at P or the arclength measure on the circle.  There is evidence for both (as the thing OP was trying to formalize) in the document and it's possible the distinction between them was not realized.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a line segment, say with a length of one. The average radius with respect to the midpoint is $1/4$, but the average radius with respect to either endpoint is $1/2$.

If you want a $2$-dimensional example, just consider a very thin rectangle where the same argument holds.

Comment: Is this for the centroid?

Comment: When you said "center of mass" earlier I assumed you meant centroid, so yes. Note that the centroid of a line segment is its midpoint, and the centroid of a rectangle is in the center of the rectangle, i.e. the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors, which corresponds to the midpoint of a line segment as the width goes to zero.

Comment: According to my calculations on sage software the centroid of the rectangle $|x/10+y|+|x/10-y|=10$ is (0,0) but so is the point with the highest average radius. Perhaps you can show me some calculation to prove me wrong.

Comment: So the rectangle in question has vertices at $(\pm 50,\pm 5)$. I got that the average radius at $(0,0)$ is about $25.32$. On the other hand, if I look at the point $(-50,0)$, then I see that at the points in the rectangle with positive $x$ coordinate (which is half of the rectangle) have distance at least $50$ from $(-50,0)$, while the points with $x$ coordinate between $-25$ and $0$ (which is $1/4$ of the triangle) have distance at least $25$ from $(-50,0)$, so without any serious calculations I see that the average radius has to be at least $1/2*50+1/4*25 = 31.25>25.32$.

Comment: See this https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/38a501f2-5b63-4b76-b720-6cadb9c3e142 to clarify your conception about the center of the rectangle.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you look a little more deeply into this.